# Extract specific FASTA sequences from a file using Perl

Tags: perl

I have written a Perl script to retrieve a hypothetical protein list from a FASTA file. I'm able to get only the header line with all hypothetical proteins, but I want to have all the sequences along with protein IDs.

The script is as follows.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $line;

open $fh, '<', '/home/Desktop/hypo_proteins/testprotein.fasta' or die "Cannot open file $fh, $!";   
open OUT, ">output.txt";

while ( $line = <$fh> ) {  

    chomp $line;

    if ( $line =~ /hypothetical protein/ ) {
        print OUT "$line\n";
    }
}

close $fh;
```

The output the I got from the above script is as follows

```
>gi|113461928|ref|YP_718205.1| hypothetical protein HS_1792 [Haemophilus somnus 129PT]
>gi|113460158|ref|YP_718214.1| hypothetical protein HS_0009 [Haemophilus somnus 129PT]
>gi|113460165|ref|YP_718221.1| hypothetical protein HS_0016 [Haemophilus somnus 129PT]
```

But I need the output as follows:

```
>gi|113461928|ref|YP_718205.1| hypothetical protein HS_1792 [Haemophilus somnus 129PT]
MFKSLIQFFKSKSNTSNIKKENAVQRQERQDIEGWITPYSGQELLNTELRQHHLGLLWQQVSMTREMFEH
LYQKPIERYAEMVQLLPASESHHHSHLGGMLDHGLEVISFAAKLRQNYVLPLNAAPEDQAKQKDAWTAAV
IYLALVHDIGKSIVDIEIQLQDGKRWLAWHGIPTLPYKFRYIKQRDYELHPVLGGFIANQLIAKETFDWL
ATYPEVFSALMYAMAGHYDKANVLAEIVQKADQNSVALALGGDITKLVQKPVISFAKQLILALRYLISQK
FKISSKGPGDGWLTEDGLWLMSKTTADQIRAYLMGQGISVPSDNRKLFDEMQAHRVIESTSEGNAIWYCQ
LSADAGWKPKDKFSLLRIKPEVIWDNIDDRPELFAGTICVVEKENEAEEKISNTVNEVQDTVPINKKENI
ELTSNLQEENTALQSLNPSQNPEVVVENCDNNSVDFLLNMFSDNNEQQVMNIPSADAEAGTTMILKSEPE
NLNTHIEVEANAIPKLPTNDDTHLKSEGQKFVDWLKDKLFKKQLTFNDRTAKVHIVNDCLFIVSPSSFEL
YLQEKGESYDEECINNLQYEFQALGLHRKRIIKNDTINFWRCKVIGPKKESFLVGYLVPNTRLFFGDKIL
INNRHLLLEE
```

Comment: can you share a sample of your input file

Comment: recommending do not reinvent the wheel again and check this https://metacpan.org/pod/GenOO (especially  the https://metacpan.org/pod/GenOO::Data::File::FASTA)

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~twylie/FASTAParse-0.0.3/lib/FASTAParse.pm

Comment: In my original answer I wrote "This is really very simple and I am disappointed that you seem to have made very little effort to resolve the problem yourself." That may be a little harsh given that you at least wrote and posted a little Perl, but the real issue here is that you don't know Perl, and it is wrong for Stack Overflow to become a place where non-programmers can get simple jobs done for free by posting them here. I suggest you spend some time [learning Perl](http://learn.perl.org/) before you ask another question so that you have at least a basic level of skill with the language

Answer (score 1):

This will do as you ask

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use constant INPUT  => '/home/Desktop/hypo_proteins/testprotein.fasta';
use constant OUTPUT => 'output.txt';

open my $in_fh,  '<', INPUT  or die "Cannot open input file: $!";   
open my $out_fh, '>', OUTPUT or die "Cannot open output file: $!";
select $out_fh;

my $print;

while ( <$in_fh> ) {  

    if ( /^>/ ) {
        $print = /hypothetical protein/;
    }

    print if $print;
}
```

Regarding your (deleted) question about this solution, it uses the *implicit* variable `$_` in several places. It is equivalent to this program

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use constant INPUT  => '/home/Desktop/hypo_proteins/testprotein.fasta';
use constant OUTPUT => 'output.txt';

open my $in_fh,  '<', INPUT  or die "Cannot open input file: $!";   
open my $out_fh, '>', OUTPUT or die "Cannot open output file: $!";
select $out_fh;

my $print;

while ( defined( $_ = <$in_fh>) ) {  

    if ( $_ =~ /^>/ ) {
        $print = ( $_ =~ /hypothetical protein/ );
    }

    print $_ if $print;
}
```

So I hope you can see that `$print = $_ =~ /hypothetical protein/` checks whether the current line (in `$_`) contains the string `hypothetical protein` and sets `$print` to a *true* value if so.

Because `$print` is defined outside the loop it keeps its value across iterations of the loop, and as you can see it is only changed on header lines, when the current line begins with `>`, and will stay true until the next header line, so that `print if $print` will output the header containing `hypothetical protein` *and all following lines* until the next header

I hope that helps

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @Mr.Llama: I'm not sure why you're citing a question that got only 16 upvotes, but the accepted answer says *"Then again; often a short snippet of code really is all that is needed"* This is really trivial Perl, and if anyone cannot understand it then they need a Perl tutorial, not an explanation

Comment: Don't take it personally, it's a canned response from [AutoReviewComments](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments).  I still stand by its sentiment though.  The provided code works, but it still doesn't explain what was incorrect about OP's code.  Omitting an explanation encourages copy/pasting as a solution instead of actual thinking and learning.

Comment: @Borodin Very nice trick. I can catch your logic. But what is the meaning of this`$print = /hypothetical protein/;` ? What are you actually doing here? Instead of this i tried binding operator `=~` and quotes, but it didn't give result.? Is this pattern matching or anything else?

Comment: @BradLarson: I am surprised to see the admonishment removed from my solution. It is commonplace to see a question rejected altogether if the author has simply published his requirement and sat back waiting for a solution. Are you saying that this question is somehow exempt, or that my words should have been put into a comment rather than the solution?

Comment: @Borodin - If you feel the question should be closed or downvoted, feel free to vote how you wish. The wording in your answer didn't add to the technical solution, was flagged by others, and received this complaint: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34594603/19679 , so I chose to remove it to focus on the solution.